# How to reshape the dataframe by adding and subtracting values in columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a data frame which looks like this,

```
   Head CHR Start   End Transcriptid    
    a   1   11869   12227   ENST1
    b   1   12613   12721   ENST8   
    c   1   13221   14409   ENST2   
    d   1   11872   12227   ENST5   
    f   1   12613   12721   ENST3
```

What I am looking for is to change the columns Start and End a little bit and get a new data frame out of it.Like, I wanted the new data file with the start as End of first Row +10 and End as Start of the second row -10 and so on for all rows.The data frame pretty big with 70,000 plus rows

So, in the end, I am aiming to get the data frame which looks like as follows, As in the last row will not have values for Start and End.

```
Head CHR Start  End  Transcriptid
a   1   12237   12603   ENST1
b   1   12731   13211   ENST8
c   1   14419   11862   ENST2
d   1   12237   12603   ENST5
f   1                   ENST3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first create new `Series` by [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.copy.html), then add `10` to column `End`. Last you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) series `start`, substract `10`:

Last you need change last value of column `Start` to `NaN` - you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
start = df['Start'].copy()
df['Start'] = df.End + 10
df['End'] = ((start.shift(-1) - 10))
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Start')] = np.nan
#if column Start is always in 3.position
#df.iloc[-1, 2] = np.nan 

print (df)
  Head  CHR    Start      End Transcriptid
0    a    1  12237.0  12603.0        ENST1
1    b    1  12731.0  13211.0        ENST8
2    c    1  14419.0  11862.0        ENST2
3    d    1  12237.0  12603.0        ENST5
4    f    1      NaN      NaN        ENST3
```

If you need empty `strings`:

```
start = df['Start'].copy()
df['Start'] = df.End + 10
df['End'] = ((start.shift(-1) - 10))
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Start')] = ''
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('End')] = ''
print (df)
  Head  CHR  Start    End Transcriptid
0    a    1  12237  12603        ENST1
1    b    1  12731  13211        ENST8
2    c    1  14419  11862        ENST2
3    d    1  12237  12603        ENST5
4    f    1                      ENST3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it has a problem here..this line df['Start'] = df.End + 10 ..is starting from second row meaning that the first Start is just The End  column of first row

Comment: Do you think last value?

Comment: Actually, the Start should be always End+10 and End should be always : Start-10. And so , for the first row the Start should be 12227-10 and so for End it's : 12613+10. I am sorry if I weren't clear enough

Comment: So you need `df['Start'], df['End'] = (df.End + 10).copy(), (df.Start - 10).copy()` ? But then output is different. Please check it. I think last value in row with  `f`  in column `Start` was typo.

Comment: Hello I have edited my question a little to clear the confusion , so the last row will not have values for start and End , because the we are starting with Start value for first from Start value from second Row -10

Comment: Thank you. Is always column `Start` third column?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean by 'third column ' . The Column Start : is always -End+10 and the column End should be always: Next start -10

Comment: Yes, The column Start is always Thrid column :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112804/discussion-between-user1017373-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

In a single step (with the exception of the last item, not clear to me if there's a typo in the question):

```
df[['Start', 'End']] = np.add([df['End'], df['Start'].shift(-1).ffill()],
                              [[10], [-10]]).T
```

Comment: Yes it's a typo and Now I have edited my question , so now as you can see the last row will not have values for start and End